# How to install python-scapy centos?

Tags: python, scapy

How can I install python-scapy on a centos server?
yum install python-scapy does not seem to work.
Do I have to download something or install a repo?
 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the *[docs:](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html)*

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget --trust-server-names https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip
$ unzip master.zip
$ cd master
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Alternatively, you can execute the zip file:

```
$ chmod +x scapy-latest.zip
$ sudo ./scapy-latest.zip
```

or:

```
$ sudo sh scapy-latest.zip
```

or:

```
$ mv scapy-latest.zip /usr/local/bin/scapy
$ sudo scapy
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ easy_install pip
$ pip install scapy
```

This usually works just fine for me. You might need a sudo in there depending on your setup.